# How to extract text from <script> tag by using nokogiri and mechanize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

this is a part of the source code of a bookings web site:

```
<script>
booking.ensureNamespaceExists('env');
booking.env.b_map_center_latitude = 53.36480155016638;
booking.env.b_map_center_longitude = -2.2752803564071655;
booking.env.b_hotel_id = '35523';
booking.env.b_query_params_no_ext = '?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaFCIAQGYAS64AQTIAQTYAQHoAQH4AQs;sid=e1c9e4c7a000518d8a3725b9bb6e5306;dcid=1';
</script>
```

And I want to extract `booking.env.b_hotel_id` . So that i would get the value of '25523'. How do I achieve this with nokogiri and mechanize?

Hope somebody can help! thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.booking.com/hotel/us/solera-by-stay-alfred.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmcgV1c19ueYgBAZgBMbgBBMgBBNgBAegBAfgBAg;sid=695d6598485cb1a8fd9e39c5de3878ba;dcid=4;checkin=2015-10-20;checkout=2015-10-21;dist=0;group_adults=2;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=cf5d76283b73d34a1d7e0d61cad6974e38a94351X1;type=total;ucfs=1&')

match = agent.page.search("script").text.scan(/^booking.env.b_hotel_id = \'.*\'/)
puts match
puts match[0].split("'")[1]
```

Output:

```
booking.env.b_hotel_id = '1202411'
1202411
```

Pages that helped me figure this out:

http://robdodson.me/crawling-pages-with-mechanize-and-nokogiri/

[Parsing javascript function elements with nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004950/parsing-javascript-function-elements-with-nokogiri)

[Regular expression - starting and ending with a character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024298/regular-expression-starting-and-ending-with-a-character-string)

http://www.rubular.com

Comment: HI thanks! but how if i want to extract other info such as b_map_center_latitude or b_map_center_longitude? will it be the same? and be like this: .scan(/^booking.env._map_center_latitude = \'.*\'/) ?

Comment: Since the value for those variables are not strings and therefore not enclosed in quotes, you would want to take away each `\'` and replace the latter one with a `\;` to limit the regex on the semicolon, like so: `/^booking.env.b_map_center_latitude = .*\;/` However, the page I found on booking.com ended each your variable declaration lines with a comma, so you might want `/^booking.env.b_map_center_latitude = .*\,/` instead. Play around with Rubular, it's fun AND educational!

Comment: I have tried /^booking.env.b_map_center_latitude = .*\,/ but got nothing in return. Just empty string...I still find this is hard to understand :(

Comment: ah dont worry! I got the answer by using ^booking.env.b_map_center_latitude = .*\; instead. Thank you! Rubular is really fun!! :)

Comment: Ah, I see why. The page has `b_hotel_id` in two places, one where the line ends with a comma and the other where it ends with a semicolon next to your other variables, which also end with semicolons.