# Search through raw code for <script> tags in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using HTTParty gem to get raw html but I am only interested in the JSON section of the code. That part of the code is nested inside a 
`<script type="text/javascript">`.

From within my Rails app how can I only select only the section I am interested in [screenshot of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq5sX.png)?

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://www.instagram.com/crossfitwanderlust_bali/')
```

Comment: maybe look a this question. Looks like exactly the same goal to me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202735/how-to-extract-text-from-script-tag-by-using-nokogiri-and-mechanize

Comment: "enter image description here" - you're supposed to enter image description there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) gem. With this, you can parse your HTML content easily.